# How to pass and get values to TreeMap on another class?

Tags: java

I am trying to simulate a production system and now I am having trouble getting and passing values to a TreeMap located on a different class.

To explain what I intend to do briefly, I will to create a Panel where I will have some textpanels to save values (for the number of parts to be added to the system) and a table where the number and parameters of the work stations on the system will be set. When I run it, those values should be stored for further processing.

On a previous question I was recommended using TreeMaps to store those values, something like:

```
Station[num][type][avg_time][posx][posy][state]
Part[num][type][state]
```

This is what I've coded so far:

L.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;    

public class L extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            L l = new L();

            TMap t = new TMap();
            t.Station("num", 127);
            t.Station("type", 3);
            //System.out.println("Entryset: " + t.keySet());
            //System.out.println("Entryset: " + t.Station() + "\n");
         }
      });

    }

 }
```

TMap.java

```
import java.util.*;

public class TMap {
    //public TreeMap <String, Integer>St = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
    public int num_atrib = 6;
    public static TreeMap<String, Integer> Station(String s,int i) {
        TreeMap <String, Integer>St = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
        St.put(s,i);
        System.out.println("Now the tree map Keys: " + St.keySet());
        System.out.println("Now the tree map contain: " + St.values());
        return St;
    }
}
```

This is outputing:

```
Now the tree map Keys: [num]
Now the tree map contain: [127]
Now the tree map Keys: [type]
Now the tree map contain: [3]
```

I have two problems, first, is this the right way to do it, because for what I see the map outputed should be [num, type] and the keys [127, 3] right?

And secondly, how can I later on get parameters from TMap on the L class, since t.keySet() for instance won't retrieve anything so far!

Hope I made myself clear, thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you're creating a new TreeMap every time you call TMap.Station. Try putting the TreeMap as a field and initializing it in a constructor instead. That should get you the map with two key/value pairs.

Answering your second question, is there any reason why you cannot make the TMap a field and just create methods to access and set? If you only instantiate it in a function, it'll disappear as soon as that function exits (plus its scope would only be in that function).

EDIT: In response to the comment...what about

EDIT EDIT: Adding rough outlines for getters. If you wanted something like a put(), it would work in a similar manner.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Set;

public class L extends JFrame {
    private TMap t;

    public L() {
        t = new TMap();
    }

    public Set<String> getKeySet() {
        return t.getKeySet();
    }

    public Integer get(String s) {
        return t.get(s);
    }

    // your main method as before
}
```

and

```
import java.util.*;

public class TMap {
    private TreeMap<String, Integer> St;
    private int num_atrib = 6;

    public TMap() {
        St = new TreeMap<String, Integer>();
    }

    public Set<String> getKeySet() {
        return St.keySet();
    }

    public Integer get(String s) {
        return St.get(s);
    }

    public static TreeMap<String, Integer> Station(String s,int i) {
        St.put(s,i);
        System.out.println("Now the tree map Keys: " + St.keySet());
        System.out.println("Now the tree map contain: " + St.values());
        return St;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry to be asking, but how can I put the TreeMap as a field?

I was trying to figure out how to create methods to access and et that map but didn't quite figure out how to!

I'm sorry for these questions but I am still somewhat new to this!

Comment: Added a rough outline of what I was talking about. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, that helped indeed. 

What if I need to get the outputs (say, keySet, values, and other) outside the TMap class? I understand you probably do it with the methods you mentioned but I am failing to see how to construct them!

Comment: Added in a getKeySet() and get() method to better explain what I mean. If you wanted to set values, you could also define a put() method in the same way.

Comment: As an aside, is there any particular reason why TMap.Station() is static?

Comment: Oh, much appretiated for your help here Dennis! I think I finally understood this and the relation between methods, fields, and so on! Regarding your question, I made it static as I was getting an error when it wasn't set as static. Any implication may arise?

Comment: Making it static would mean that you need to make everything it touches static too, which is definitely not want you want. Each field appears to be unique to a specific instance of the class, so I don't think it should be static.

Also, it's generally better practice to keep all the fields private. Leaving them public means that you *could* do something like t.St.keySet() directly, but exposing that much of a class is generally not a good idea.

Comment: You really gave me a nice lesson here, much much appretiated! I was able to utilize the code + concepts you gave me correctly, but I just came across a new problem that I hadn't thought through previously.

Imagine I have more than one "Station", if I re-put a value over let's say "num" the first one will be overwritten. This meaning, I don't think creating several TreeMaps, one for each station is a very good practice, is there a better way to do it?

Comment: That really depends on what you're trying to get out of the program; I can't really help unless I know how you're using the TreeMap. Put up another question that better describes how you're using TreeMap, and ask for help resolving that. Other users can then provide their advice, and perhaps someone will think of something that will help you there.